# Symfony Client & DomCrawler: Post with query string

Tags: symfony

I'm having issues attempting to POST to a script that requires a query string. I'm using the code below, but I get the same error response I would get if I requested the page without the query string or set the query variable to "".

For example `http://example.com/login?validate` works in the browser, but `http://example.com/login?validate=""` does not (page displays error)

My code:

```
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request("POST","https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/login?validate", array(
    'USERNAME' => 'TEST',
    'PASSWORD' => 'TEST'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

*Normally you would use the route like this:*

```
$client->request('POST', '/login', array(
    'USERNAME' => 'TEST',
    'PASSWORD' => 'TEST'
    )
);
```

---

In your particular case, I don't think you need to add `?validate` as it should be triggered when you submit the form:

```
$client->request('POST', 'https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/login', array(
    'USERNAME' => 'TEST',
    'PASSWORD' => 'TEST'
    )
);
```

---

Also, make sure your field is `USERNAME` and not `username`, it is case sensitive.

Comment: Unfortunatley the system I'm connecting to is very old and dated. I need to have the ?validate in the request otherwise the server's script will fail. It seems that there is an "=" (equal sign) being appended to the REQUEST_URI and that may be the culprit, now I just need to figure out how to override the URI.